# Collecting coefficients of non-commutative products from an expression

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation, coefficients, ncalgebra

I am trying to manipulate a Hamiltonian with non-commutative operators, $a_j,a_j^\dagger$. After some algebra using NCAlgebra package in Mathematica, I have an expression like, $$H = C_1 (b**a) + C_2 (a**a^\dagger) + C_3 (d^\dagger d) + \cdots $$
How do I extract/collect coefficients like $C_1,C_2$? I have tried `NCCollect[H, b**a]`, but it does not give me the desired answer $C_1$?
I am new to this and appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. This question lacks a minimal working example. Please paste (enough) Mma code that replicates your problem.

Comment: Maybe `NCCoefficientList[expr, {a, b}]`?

Comment: Thank you @march and @Syed. It turns out, there was a simple solution. The command`Coefficient[expr, SuperStar[b1] ** b2]` did the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `NCCoefficientList` as in:

```
H = C1 b ** a + C2 a ** aj[a] + C3 d ** aj[d]
NCCoefficientList[H, {a, aj[a], b, d, aj[d]}]
```

which returns

> {C1, C2, C3}

Note that you have to add also `aj[a]` and `aj[d]` to the list of variables.